How can I get the `session_uid` used by the Bake geometry node using Python?
I need to bake a part of my node tree via the bake node for an add-on. This requires a correct session_uid to press the button with Python.

I already tried bpy.data.node_groups["Geometry Nodes"].session_uid, which wasn't the same:


Can you explain, how did you get the  bake_id - to run bake operator?

Ok, got it in - obj.modifiers['GeometryNodes'].bakes[x].bake_id

So we got session_id, and bake_id - but how do we match them to  bake_node? If there is only one bake_node, then  we can  use (sessionn_uid,  obj.mods[].bake[0].bake_id), but what if we have multiple bake nodes - how to match them to proper  obj.mods.bake[?].bake_id  ?

You can get this id from the object:
bpy.context.active_object.id_data.session_uid

