Batch baking geometry nodes
I have geometry nodes with simulation zones on a lot of objects. To enable remote rendering I want to bake the geometry nodes for each object (yay blender 4.1!).
Is there a way to bake them all in one go, rather than have to bake each one one-by-one? I tried selecting them all and alt-clicking the bake button, but it didn't work.
Baking them one by one is going to take forever.

You could write a python script that iterates over each object and bake it. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/318518/how-can-i-get-the-session-uid-used-by-the-bake-geometry-node-using-python#318520

Yeah, I was thinking that was going to be the solution. Looks a little tricky.
